# debounce Lodash - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to use loadash debounce in my text input (React Native App). 
Why isn't my debounce working correctly?? the input value inside the textInput disappears/re-appears as I hit backspace.

```
              handleSearch(text, bool){
                 // search logic here
                }

                   <TextInput  
                    value={value} 
                    onChangeText={_.debounce((text) =>{this.handleSearch(text, true);this.setFlat(true);this.renderDropDown(false)},200)}  
                    onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                      if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace' && value !== "") {
                        this.handleClearText();
                      }     
                      if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace' && value === "") {
                        this.handleClearFilter();
                      }             
                    }}  
                  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the callback the way it was meant. If you keep it like this, every time your component is rendered that piece of code is being executed, besides if that render was fired because that event.

You should move that code to and method/function, and asign that method/function as callback. Something like this:

```
const handleTextChange = _.debounce((text) =>{
    this.handleSearch(text,true);
    this.setFlat(true);
    this.renderDropDown(false)
},200);

/* .... */

<TextInput  
    value={value} 
    onChangeText={handleTextChahge}    
/>
```

Comment: Noted thanks a lot. Please check my updated question again. I have added "onKeyPress" to my text input. Now this prop is not letting my debounce work. I implemented this to clear out my "search filters" (it appears as a label inside the text input). Because of this native event every time I hit BackSpace the search value inside text input disappears/re-appears LOL. I remove "onKeyPress" debounce works perfectly fine. Any suggestions on how to incorporate both???

Comment: It sounds like the `onKeyPress` event is fired before than `onChangeText`. You should handle everything on the `onKeyPress`. In any case, clearing the whole text input with the backspace key sounds like a bad UX to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.onChangeTextDelayed = _.debounce(this.onChangeText, 2000);
  }

  onChangeText(text) {
    console.log("debouncing");
  }

  render() {
    return <Input onChangeText={this.onChangeTextDelayed} />
```

Comment: Noted thanks a lot. Please check my updated question again. I have added "onKeyPress" to my text input. Now this prop is not letting my debounce work. I implemented this to clear out my "search filters" (it appears as a label inside the text input). Because of this native event every time I hit BackSpace the search value inside text input disappears/re-appears LOL. I remove "onKeyPress" debounce works perfectly fine. Any suggestions on how to incorporate both???

Answer (score 1):

How do you import loadash? Can you try this?

```
  import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

  <TextInput
    value={value}
    onChangeText={debounce((text) => {
      
    this.handleSearch(text,true);
    this.setFlat(true);
    this.renderDropDown(false) 
    }, 300)}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    style={styles.textInput}
  />
```